# PHP: Whenever I use if !isset I get this error: "undefined index"

Tags: php, calculator, isset

This is my php code so far for my calculator application. Im trying to make it so that whenever a user does not check one of the multiple (4) radio button to use a counting method there will be a warning that tells the user that they have to use a counting method.
But what happens instead is this:

> Notice Undefined index:typ in C:\xampp\htdocs\labb1\miniraknare.php on line 13
>   Mata in ett räknesätt!

I get the correct response that I want from the application, but I dont know how to get rid of the notice. How do I fix this?

This is my code:

```
<?php

$miniraknare1 = $_POST['siffra1'];
$miniraknare2 = $_POST['siffra2'];
$miniraknaretyp = $_POST['typ'];

if (is_numeric($miniraknare1) && is_numeric($miniraknare2)){

    if (!isset($miniraknaretyp)) {
        echo("Mata in ett räknesätt!");
    }

    if($miniraknaretyp=="addition"){
        echo $miniraknaretyp . " " . "Resultatet är:" . " " . 
              ($miniraknare1+$miniraknare2);
    }

    if($miniraknaretyp=="subtraktion"){
        echo $miniraknaretyp . " " . "Resultatet är:" . " " . 
            ($miniraknare1-$miniraknare2);
    }

    if($miniraknaretyp=="multiplikation"){
        echo $miniraknaretyp . " " . "Resultatet är:" . " " . 
            ($miniraknare1*$miniraknare2);
    }

    if($miniraknaretyp=="division"){
        echo $miniraknaretyp . " " . "Resultatet är:" . " " . 
            ($miniraknare1/$miniraknare2);
    }
}
else {
    echo "Ditt inmatade värde är felaktigt";
}

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Line 13 is this line: `$miniraknaretyp = $_POST['typ'];`

**This is my HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Inlämningsuppgift 1 – miniraknare.php</title>        
    </head>

    <body>

    Ange två siffror och välj beräkningssätt:
    <form action="miniraknare.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="siffra1" />
        <input type="radio" name="typ" value="addition" />+
        <input type="radio" name="typ" value="subtraktion" />-
        <input type="radio" name="typ" value="multiplikation" />*   
        <input type="radio" name="typ" value="division" />/
        <input type="text" name="siffra2" /><br />  
        <input type="submit" name="skicka" />
    </form>
    <br />
    <br />


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Show us the HTML form that goes with this to be 100% certain.

Comment: This says to me you do not have a field with a `name="typ"` on the calling `<form>`

Comment: Ok, there's nothing wrong with your code, at least for what you **posted**. I suspect you have your entire code (HTML/PHP) set inside the same file, correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Sidenote: This I tested before posting.*

There isn't anything wrong with your code.

*What I suspect is,* your entire codes (HTML form and PHP) are inside the same page and that is why you are getting the "Undefined index" warning, as this is normal upon initial page load, because nothing has been chosen for the radio button, or entered a number in the form fields.

Either you split those codes up to be their own file, or use `isset()` in conjunction with the named submit button, also checking to see if the radio button is set and that the fields where you enter a number, are not empty.

If you are using the entire code in one file and wish to remain it as such, modify your submit button to this: (*I only added the word "Submit" to it*)

```
<input type="submit" name="skicka" value="Submit" />
```

then do, and using `empty()` for the `siffra1` and `siffra2` elements:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['skicka'])  
   && isset($_POST['typ'])  
   && !empty($_POST['siffra1']) 
   && !empty($_POST['siffra2']) ){

$miniraknare1 = $_POST['siffra1'];
$miniraknare2 = $_POST['siffra2'];
$miniraknaretyp = $_POST['typ'];

if (is_numeric($miniraknare1) && is_numeric($miniraknare2)){

    if (!isset($miniraknaretyp)) {
        echo("Mata in ett räknesätt!");
    }

    if($miniraknaretyp=="addition"){
        echo $miniraknaretyp . " " . "Resultatet är:" . " " . 
              ($miniraknare1+$miniraknare2);
    }

    if($miniraknaretyp=="subtraktion"){
        echo $miniraknaretyp . " " . "Resultatet är:" . " " . 
            ($miniraknare1-$miniraknare2);
    }

    if($miniraknaretyp=="multiplikation"){
        echo $miniraknaretyp . " " . "Resultatet är:" . " " . 
            ($miniraknare1*$miniraknare2);
    }

    if($miniraknaretyp=="division"){
        echo $miniraknaretyp . " " . "Resultatet är:" . " " . 
            ($miniraknare1/$miniraknare2);
    }
}
else {
    echo "Ditt inmatade värde är felaktigt";
    }

} // brace for if(isset($_POST['skicka']))

?>

</body>
</html>
```

---

You could also add an `else`

```
} // brace for if(isset($_POST['skicka']))

else{
echo "Nothing is set.";
}
```

---

> *Thank you, its just that I need the message "Mata in ett räknesätt" to show up if the user doesnt use a calculating method. But the message isnt showing up. How do I make it show up?*

**Edit:**

Change this whole block in my code above:

```
if(isset($_POST['skicka'])  
   && isset($_POST['typ'])  
   && !empty($_POST['siffra1']) 
   && !empty($_POST['siffra2']) ){
```

to

```
if(isset($_POST['skicka']) ){
```

---

Comment: ah! It wasn't a typo. And i bet 5$ xD

Comment: @Rizier123 Nope, it wasn't a typo as I originally thought. I thought it was because the OP didn't originally post the HTML form that goes with it (which could have been it, but it wasn't). So, this makes a lot more sense now, suspecting OP is using entire code inside the same page. Here's your `$5.00` ;)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thank you, its just that I need the message "Mata in ett räknesätt" to show up if the user doesnt use a calculating method. But the message isnt showing up. How do I make it show up?

Comment: You're welcome. Look near the bottom where it says "You could also add an `else`". You can change `echo "Nothing is set.";` to `echo "Whatever message.";` @PHPScrub

Comment: @PHPScrub Ok, I have another solution. Give me a minute. I will make additional notes near the bottom.

Comment: @PHPScrub Reload my answer and look at the instructions I left under **Edit**.

Answer (score 1):

```
$miniraknare1 = $_POST['siffra1'];
$miniraknare2 = $_POST['siffra2'];

if(isset($_POST['typ']))
   $miniraknaretyp = $_POST['typ'];
else
   echo("Mata in ett räknesätt!");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check isset around $_POST['typ'];

```
 if(isset($_POST['typ'])) {
     $miniraknaretyp = $_POST['typ'];
 }
```

Then you need

```
if (!isset($miniraknaretyp)) {
    echo("Mata in ett räknesätt!");
} else {

    if($miniraknaretyp=="addition"){
        echo $miniraknaretyp . " " . "Resultatet är:" . " " . ($miniraknare1+$miniraknare2);
    }

    if($miniraknaretyp=="subtraktion"){
        echo $miniraknaretyp . " " . "Resultatet är:" . " " . ($miniraknare1-$miniraknare2);
    }

    if($miniraknaretyp=="multiplikation"){
        echo $miniraknaretyp . " " . "Resultatet är:" . " " . ($miniraknare1*$miniraknare2);
    }

    if($miniraknaretyp=="division"){
           echo $miniraknaretyp . " " . "Resultatet är:" . " " . ($miniraknare1/$miniraknare2);
    }
}
```

Comment: What about the other two? Why isn't OP not getting an error for those? I'm next to convinced it's a typo or form element isn't named.

Comment: In this case they are both set. But you are right, he should check them all for good practice. I also think it is a typo but he says it has the desired effect apart from the notice.

Comment: Yeah, the `isset()` is indeed a good method. Will wait to see what the OP has to say ;)

Comment: The OP could also wrapp all the PHP in `if($_POST){}` just to check if the page is actually posted. after that he can also do a check on what is posted with `foreach($_POST as $field => $value) {echo 'Field: '.$field.' value: '.$value.'<br>';}`

Comment: You are actually just moving the error from `$_POST['typ']` to `$miniraknaretyp` as if `$_POST['typ']` is not set neither will `$miniraknaretyp` be, so when you come to use that you will get a `Undefined variable error` so add an ELSE and set `$miniraknaretyp` to a default value

Comment: Well he is checking if it is not set already. I guess he should exit there or something.

Comment: I got another error when I used this code: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\labb1\miniraknare.php on line 38 (which is the second or last else  used)

Comment: You have to use it withint the existing if (is_numeric($miniraknare1) && is_numeric($miniraknare2)){} Make sure you haven't replaced the closing breacket of this outter if

Comment: @AntonyD'Andrea I did. But it still gives me error "unexpected else". I added the HTML code to my initial post. I still havent been able to figure out a solution for two days now.

Answer (score 0):

If `typ` is your set of radio buttons and you cannot proceed without one of them being checked then the first thing this script should do is test if it was passed a value in that field.

Remember, if none of the radio buttons are checked by the user **NOTHING** is sent in the POST for that fieldname, so there will just be no occurance in the $_POST array for that field.

```
if ( ! isset($_POST['typ']) ) {
    echo 'You must click one of the radio buttons';
    // exit or something like it as continuing would be pointless
}
```

Do this before any of this

```
$miniraknare1 = $_POST['siffra1'];
$miniraknare2 = $_POST['siffra2'];
$miniraknaretyp = $_POST['typ'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are currently checking if the variable `$miniraknaretyp` is set, but earlier on in this code. You are assigning these variables by referencing a global array without using `isset` so PHP is expecting the indexes to be set. The lines in question are:

```
$miniraknare1 = $_POST['siffra1'];
$miniraknare2 = $_POST['siffra2'];
$miniraknaretyp = $_POST['typ'];
```

Essentially, PHP is thinking: 
*Dev is using array keys, these should be set*      --- but truth of the matter is that they are not being filled correctly from your HTML form. So the solution to stop this error being thrown is:

```
if (isset($_POST['typ'])){
  $miniraknare1 = $_POST['typ'];
}
```

if you are sure these indexes should be populated, but are not.. Then i'd suggest the simple debugging techniques of:

1. Checking for typos between the HTML form and PHP validation
2. `echo "<pre>"; var_dump($_POST); echo "</pre>";` on the validation side to check what is happening to your `post` array after being submitted

Make changes according to your scenario. It's awkward to tell what's going on as we're not seeing all the code available Ie. the HTML.

Comment: He says it is giving the correct response but with that notice. So a simple isset is all that is needed.

Comment: I added the HTML, also I dont know how to add the code that you suggested on the validation side...

Answer (score -1):

or you can try like this:

```
  if (!isset($miniraknaretyp)) {
$miniraknaretyp = $_POST['typ'];
     echo("Mata in ett räknesätt!");
}
```

Comment: And if $_POST['typ'] isn't set? Where the error actually is?!

Comment: yeah my bad i forgot the else. (and this assuming he declared $_POST['typ'])